# dynamic forms asp.net

Tags: asp.net, forms, dynamic

Today i'm using crystal reports to create parameterized forms and save them into PDF, but isn't there other alternatives?

What i want to do? Well, simply have a form with information "placeholders" (that's how i'm using crystal) ... then in code i set the placeholder data to be binded ... Save as PDF and voila...

But crystal is a pain to maintain and the fields don't grow automatically.

Thank U All..
Tiago.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to generate PDF's without Crystal. [iTextSharp](http://csharp-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries/itextsharp) is one. You can also use [XSL Formatting objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL_Formatting_Objects) to do with a transform

Answer (score 0):

Why not use ASP.NET page it self as a template - you can use various controls (including templated ones such as grid view, repeater) and then bind data using usual data-binding ways. User server.execute to run the page and capture html output. Now convert it to PDF using numerous tools/libraries (e.g. ABCPdf.Net) that are available for the same.